# Magento 2 - How to create custom EAV entity with backend crud operations

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

I want to create custom EAV entity module with back-end crud operations like in Magento default Product Attributes functionalities.

So i can create new attribute multiselect, dropdown, text and etc..
in my custom module also assign attribute set.

If you know any solution please let me know.

Comment: Hi Ravi, Did you found any solution related to this question?

Comment: You can use UMC (Ultimate Module Creator) Extension.

Comment: Can you please upload link ?

Comment: check this one https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc